# unable to query SQL Server using ExecuteScalar

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

unable to prevent duplicate email

I am using asp.net c# and trying to show the message(email already exist) when the user enters the duplicated email. but it didn't work.

here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        string checkUser = "select count(*) from table where email='" + emailField.Text + "'";

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkUser, con);
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        if (temp == 1)
        {
            Response.Write("email already exist");

        }

        con.Close();
    }

}
```

Comment: What "didn't work"? Is there an error message?

Comment: what about,  int.Parse(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString()); ?

Comment: @eddie_cat there is no error message, but it allows the user to enter duplicate email

Comment: Beware of [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/). You are using `COUNT` in your query when you really care about `EXISTS`. Then you check the count, in a roundabout way, for the value `1`. Perhaps it's already more than `1`.

Comment: @saj I tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: `if (temp > 0)`, try that

Comment: What is the value of temp ?

Comment: Debugging skills are important.  Separate your execute into steps, first say `var result = com.ExecuteScalar();` on one line, then `int temp = Convert.ToInt32(result);` on the next line and set a breakpoint there.  Tell us what the value of `result` is at that breakpoint.

Comment: Also use command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmailField.Text) to avoid Sql Injection.

Comment: You should also have your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` in `using` blocks: `using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(...)){...using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkUser, con)){int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString()); if (temp == 1){Response.Write("email already exist");}}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to make this a comment but it's too long...

Did you check your html?  I don't think `Response.Write` replaces the page so you might have that before your html tags and not be able to see it.  Is there something to end the response?

Shouldn't you set a variable or label to display the message on your page instead of using response.write?

Where's the insert into your database?  Is it happening anyway in an event like `buttonAdd_Click()`?  Again, this code in Page_Load gets executed before that handler but the handler still gets executed.

You should use command parameters to prevent injection.  What would happen if someone enters this email address?

```
'; drop table [table];--
```

Parameters are easy, just change the query and add the parameter:

```
string checkUser = "select count(*) from table where email=@email";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkUser, con);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", emailField.Text);
```

Comment: yes I put the insert in buttonAdd_Click(), but should I put the check email code in the page_load() or in  buttonAdd_Click() ?

Comment: @HbkHhh Even though it works be aware, you really should use `using` statements.  They implement the `IDispose` which will allocate resources better.  My example is below.

Comment: The check should be in the same method you insert it with and the insert should be avoided depending on the result.

Answer (score 1):

Equals `=` is used for exact matches in SQL, this means that if your field is a varchar with extra spaces or the value from your textbox has them, the string will not match.

Consider using:

```
 "select count(*) from table where LTRIM(RTRIM(email))='" + emailField.Text.Trim() + "'";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string checkUser = "select count(*) from table where email=@email";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(checkUser, conn);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", emailField.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed quite a bit with your code:

- Page Load (What event actually triggers this call, currently it always happens at Page Load.)
- Your not using Parameters, which makes your code susceptible to SQL Injection.
- Your converting the Database Object directly to a `string` (ie: `null`)
- The Response usually triggers, but your doing it at Page Load which could make it not trigger.

Some of the things you could do would be:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```

When a button is selected, the event will be called on the `Postback`.  Which should call the method that should be in the `Page Load` not the actually functionality.

The method should look like this:

```
private void DuplicateEmail()
{
     if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmail))
         return;

     int row = 0;
     string query = @"SELECT * FROM [SomeTable] WHERE ([Email] = @Email);";

     using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager...))
          using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
          {
               connection.Open();
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
               row = (Int32)command.ExecuteScalar();

               if(row == 1)
               {
                   // Call alert.
               }
           }
}
```

You can call the `Response`, or you can use a `Page.RegisterClientScript` which will allow you to call a Javascript alert; which may be more beneficial than a `Response`.

Hopefully that points you in a solid direction.